# How to take a watch on registry by programmatically ?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-7, registry, driver

How to take a watch in registry in windows, so that when any value in registry is supposed to modified then there should be pop up?

Comment: Check out `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Do note that `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()` does not tell you WHICH value was changed, though. To figure that you, you would have to keep track of the value(s) you are interested in and compare them individually as needed. Or else use a lower-level kernel hook, which provides more detailed information.